# How can I multiply all values of a column except one in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, multiplication

I have a data frame

```
Note <- c("Revenue","Profit", "EPS", "Receipts", "Cash")
HY2020 <- c(1:5)
HY2019 <- c(6:10)

df <- data.frame(Note, HY2020, HY2019)
```

Is there a way to multiply the columns **HY2020** and **HY2019** by 1000 but leave the 'EPS' row unchanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a logical vector based on the 'Note' column.  Use that to subset the rows, select the columns except the first column, multiply by 1000, and update by assignment  (`<-`) back to the original same subset data

```
i1 <- df$Note != "EPS"
df[i1, -1] <- df[i1, -1] * 1000
```

---

Or we use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
     mutate(across(starts_with("HY"),
           ~ case_when(Note != "EPS" ~ . * 1000, TRUE ~ as.numeric(.))))
```

-output

```
df
 Note HY2020 HY2019
1  Revenue   1000   6000
2   Profit   2000   7000
3      EPS      3      8
4 Receipts   4000   9000
5     Cash   5000  10000
```

---

Or in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Note != "EPS", (names(df)[-1]) := lapply(.SD, `*`, 1000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R code with `ifelse`

```
> df[-1] <- df[-1] * ifelse(df$Note != "EPS", 1000, 1)

> df
      Note HY2020 HY2019
1  Revenue   1000   6000
2   Profit   2000   7000
3      EPS      3      8
4 Receipts   4000   9000
5     Cash   5000  10000
```